# What is the steepest gradient that a canal can be traversable without locks?

Tags: transportation, rivers

For a civilization that depends heavily on canals for transportation, what limits are there on how steep canals can before they flow too fast to traverse? I know that barges were normally pulled by animals upriver, if winds were unfavorable, so would the maximum slope of the canal depend on how strong the beasts of burden are? It would be neat to be able to calculate the slope in like meters dropped per kilometer in a general sense.

Comment: Going downstream, you could go all the way to 90 degrees if you wanted to. White water rafting with cargo.

Comment: You can be the first on the pulleys to lift the barge back up the cliff.

Comment: Use inflatables - safer for the ferrymen / adventurers, and easier to get back up the cliff later on. Seriously though, one of the issues you're going to face with this question is *displacement*. The mass of the cargo is only part of the equation, the force of the water against the hull is going to be another major factor, and the answer to this is likely going to be based on the shape of the hulls you use for transport.

Comment: It isn't having to go uphill that would be the problem.  The real problem would be the speed of the water rushing downhill.  As soon as that speed gets anywhere near the speed of your boat, your're not going to go anywhere.  And it doesn't take much of an angle to make water flow quickly.  If you can notice a slope, you're not going to be sailing up it.  The Mississippi is long and navigable, and it rises only .12m per kilometre.  That's .012%.  The purpose of locks is to eliminate the slope.

Comment: This seems to be what you want : https://www.lmnoeng.com/Channels/trapezoid.php

Comment: Or maybe the rectangular if you want animals : https://www.lmnoeng.com/water.php

Comment: You'd still need to calculate how fast the animals can pull the barge and take that into account to for maximum flow that is okay to have.

Comment: The problem is never how hard it is to pull barges upstream, the problem is always how to keep the canal filled with water. If the canal has any amount of appreciable slope water will flow downhill. Where does the water come from?

Comment: Are you limited to draught animals on a towpath, or are your barges motorised ?

Comment: Towed by animal, though not limited to horses or oxen, animals like mammoths, rhinos, and triceratops have been domesticated so there is a fair amount of power available.

Comment: Why are there no human powered barges? Ships used to have dozens or hundreds of people with oars to row boat.  Either that or have an animal powered paddle wheel on the deck of the barge.

Comment: What tech level is available?

Comment: Late medieval, so no steam power but there are some crude explosives and there are too many unemployed workers with steel tools ready to dig ditches.

Comment: couldn't you sculpt the tilted canal as a Tesla valve, thereby limiting your flow? Would make for a varied riverscape as well... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_valve

Comment: @AlexP a river. Simple as that

Comment: Alright then, what is the steepest gradient a river can be before it is no longer traversable by barges pulled by manpower or animals?

Comment: @Hobbamok: And what's the depth of a river which has any appreciable slope? Is such a river navigable by anything other than a raft? Are there any examples of rivers navigable enough to carry barges which have a slope of more than, say, 5‰ or 0°17′?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A canal with a gradient and a flow is a river. And navigatable rivers are pretty much flat.  Taking a nearby river (the Medway) and measuring the change in height from the coast to the point at which it becomes essentially unnavigatable gives an average gradient of **0.0003** or about 30cm per kilometer. Wider rivers have lower gradients. The Mississippi has a gradient of about [1cm per km,](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Mississippi-River-gradient-plotted-between-New-Orleans-and-Head-of-Passes-the-site_fig4_222406982) yet still flows pretty quickly

If you have a flowing canal, you need a constant source of water. This is why canals use locks. Don't design canals as rivers, unless you already have a river to redirect through it.

Comment: And here I was going to suggest canals filled with high-viscosity fluid, thus greatly diminishing the flow rate.  Just coat your barges with some magic fluid-phobic material so there's no friction resistance.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Traditionally one uses the highly viscous fluid called asphalt for this, I'm just not sure if wheels count as magic friction reducing material...

Comment: If you have two bodies of water at different heights, then the higher one will supply the water.

Comment: Having a flowing canal isn't a goal, it's an unfortunate consequence of having to move between two bodies of water at different heights.

Comment: @Acccumulation And what happens when that body of water is empty?

Comment: @immibis 1. It won't empty; the flow will stop once it reaches the height of the other body of water. 2. The question just asks whether you can build a canal between two bodies of water *that are currently at different heights*, it doesn't ask whether you can build a canal and *keep* different heights.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft true, tires are not but the bearings your wheels rotate on are pretty special and very low friction

Comment: @Acccumulation A canal that is half dry is no longer a canal, but an inlet. =P

Answer (score 14):

> The Suez Canal is an artificial waterway of about 190 km in length running across the Isthmus of Suez in northeastern Egypt which connects the Mediterranean Seas with the Gulf of Suez, an arm of the Red Sea.  It has no locks, because the Mediterranean Sea and the Gulf of Suez have roughly the same water level and is thus the world's longest canal without locks.  ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=WeocAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=%22longest+canal+without+locks%22&source=bl&ots=6N-yAp7iED&sig=ACfU3U3_tQk9O2mmCAf50D9__arNRlYGow&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEqdHI-MHhAhXpoYMKHXoODPYQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22longest%20canal%20without%20locks%22&f=false))
>
> Karakum Canal without locks in Russia is the longest canal in the world with a total length of 1400 kilometer. It was built in 1954 and completed in 1967 having a length of 840 kilometers and further extended in 1970 and 80s up to Caspian Sea coast making its total length of 1400 kilometers. ([Source](http://allpaedia.com/mobile/general-knowledge/longest-in-the-world/3129-longest-canal-in-the-world.html))

**To answer your question, 0°.**

The differences in "sea level altitude" between the sources and destinations of these bodies varies naturally according to the tide, but the canals are dug such that those variations are accommodated within the canal — which can only be done when the source and destination altitudes are fundamentally equal.

There is obviously some small amount of ascent/descent or the canals/rivers used for cargo transport wouldn't have a current.  But that ascent/descent need not (and almost always is not) a condition of the path being traveled by the cargo ships.  For example, the Mississippi has nearly all of its descent in its northern most reaches.  By the time you get to the majority of shipping in the southern U.S., it's basically flat.  The current is caused by water pressure from the north.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about sea canals; more the medieval style "river canals". They definitely have different water levels across the length of the canal, though obviously, they also used a *lot* of locks. 2° is the kind of grade that already gives trouble to rail traffic, I'd expect a navigable river/canal system would be substantially below 1°, especially without powered boats. Many navigable rivers have gradients in tens of centimeters per kilometer. And of course, even if a gradient is technically possible, at some point land traffic is going to be more economical anyway.

Comment: you could not have any gradient over the entire length.

Comment: @jwenting uh, yeah you could. Literally all rivers have that. And what are canals if not redirected rivers or lakes?

Comment: @Hobbamok you could not, unless you want to drain one end of the canal into the other. A river has something where the water originates, or it'd run dry. Canals with a grade would drain whatever is at their high point into whatever is at their low point. Which can drain entire lakes.

Comment: @jwenting and what if, just hypothetically, we use a river instead of a lake, you know this body of water which is literally constantly draining?
As I already said "literally all rivers have that. And what are canals if not redirected rivers [...] ?"

Comment: 1 degree is a 1:60 gradient, or 16m per km - that's around 100 times steeper than most navigable rivers.

Comment: @RobinBennett, that was the kind of info I was hunting for but couldn't find.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: "The current is caused by water pressure from the north." [citation needed]  This isn't a pipeline.

Comment: @Yakk, all rivers are pipelines.  Consider what happens when they exit a mountain into a wide valley.  Same thing.

Comment: @JBH No, they are troughs.  Very different response to pressure.  If you apply pressure to a trough, you get a vertical wave; the water *gains height* in response to pressure, because water doesn't like being compressed; the same does not happen in a pipeline.  Rivers are free to gain height, the only thing that stops them is gravity, and that is far "easier" than maintaining a "pressure wave" over any distance.  I'd bet dollars to donuts that the (even extremely tiny) average slope of water of the mississippi explains its flow to 999 parts in 1000 or more.

Comment: @Yakk, hmmm... you're describing a step response.  I'd need proof.

Comment: @Yakk Granted this would raise the river height next to the higher water, but then you have just reinvented the same problem. There exists water at a higher height near water at a lower height. It will balance out, this will induce a current. So in broad terms it would still effectively drain the higher body of water. until the height across the entire body of water matches (excluding lunar influences and small variations due literal waves in the water).

Comment: I'm sure a lot of people living near the banks of the Mississippi would be very happy if increased pressure within the river just made it flow faster instead of causing it to flood.

Answer (score 7):

The gradient should be 0, UNLESS the high end of the canal has a flow rate high enough to compensate for the amount of water being drained from it by the canal into the low end.

Which for any decent sized canal would be a lot indeed and probably make the upstream end of the canal hazardous for shipping because of the rapids.

This is simple physics. Water (as any liquid really) want to establish equilibrium, meaning the surface wants to be flat and level. Thus it flows from high to low until equilibrium is established, both vessels having the same water level.

The only way to thus have a canal with one end higher than the other without an artificial barrier (a lock) in it is to ensure that the high end gains water as fast as the canal can drain it.

In theory of course you could calculate the exact drainage and pump water out of the low end at that rate, back into the high end. But locks would be much easier, cheaper, and more reliable.

Comment: * where "flat" and "level" are non-technical terms referring to the imperceptible curve that water follows to maintain an equal gravitational potential...

Comment: You don't need a pump, if natural processes are filling it up. And even if there's a net flow, it can still take years to level off, if the flow is small enough and the volume is large enough.

Comment: @Acccumulation A canal dependent civilisation, requires functional canals. Investing in a Canal that would suffer at the hands of intermittent weather, or potentially would ruin the already established network of canals is a bad investment. It would be like investing in a rail line which would work fine for the next 10 years except for droughts, and will prevent any trains on linked rails from running after that. Requiring either a massive refurbishment program or new technology to fix.

Comment: @Kain0_0 I'm taking the the desire for flow to be motivated by out-of-universe plot reasons, and not an in-universe desire of the characters. And according to [this article](https://phys.org/news/2009-12-mediterranean-sea-years.html), it would take the Amazon six years to empty a body of water the size of the Mediterranean Sea. So if you had a canal with a flow one hundredth of the Amazon, it would take six hundred years. And with rain, it wouldn't suffer at the hand of intermittent weather, since it would take six hundred years of drought to empty it.

Answer (score 1):

Your only limiter is how much your beasts of burden can drag up river. This is less dependent on slope than it is on the speed of flow and shape of the hull. Personally I'd favour double hulled boats if your channel is wide enough, they cut through water pretty well while giving you width for cargo space. Whereas a similar single hull would probably need to be a long thin boat in a heavy current.

Comment: So, the more hydrodynamic the boat hull is, the easier it is to be pulled through the water. That sort of makes sense.

Comment: The limiter is that the water will flow out of your canal at the bottom end leaving it empty of water, unless it is refilled at the top, in which case it is a river.

Comment: If you're talking about a catamaran, they're generally referred to as twin-hulled. "Double hull" generally refers to a hull inside a hull.

Comment: @Acccumulation maybe where you come from, over here no, and I'm Polynesian, we invented these vessels over 2000 years ago.

Comment: @Kilisi "Hull" is not a Polynesian term. While "double hull" can refer to catamarans, "twin-hulled" is significantly less ambiguous.

Comment: @Acccumulation you speak Polynesian or just making stuff up... catamaran isn't an English word depending how you look at it If you have trouble understanding what I meant I can't really help you with that..

Comment: Now you're being completely incoherent.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if [Tesla valve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEnHi9L0Oy8)-shaped channel would work for you. It can make flow 10-100 times slower than unimpeded one, so I guess in theory 1/10 gradient would become possible. But it works best with pulsed flow and when covered so I am not sure if it would work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If your canal empties into the [Bay of Fundy](http://bayoffundytourism.com/worlds-highest-tides/), you've got fifty feet of vertical displacement to work with, thanks to the tides.

You can achieve whatever angle you might fancy by varying the length of your canal.